# Error: tuple index out of range python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Maybe you can give me your advise?

I have a web page `clarity-project.info/tenders/…` and I need to extract `data-id="<some number>"` and write them in a new file

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
url = 'https://clarity-project.info/tenders/?entiy=38163425&offset=100'
agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3)AppleWebKit/537.36\
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'

request = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': agent})

html = urlopen(request).read().decode()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.get('data-id', None) is not None)
with open('/Users/tinasosiak/Documents/number.txt', 'a') as f:
    for tag in tags:
       print(tag['data-id'])
       np.savetxt(f, 'data-id')
```

But when I run my code, I get this error:

```
1f1d2745f1b641c6bd6831288b49d54e
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-556a89a7507f> in <module>()
     15     for tag in tags:
     16         print(tag['data-id'])
---> 17         np.savetxt(f, 'data-id')
     18 

/Users/tinasosiak/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments)
   1212                 ncol = len(X.dtype.descr)
   1213         else:
-> 1214             ncol = X.shape[1]
   1215 
   1216         iscomplex_X = np.iscomplexobj(X)

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: You're not referring to your tag element when you call save at least, did you mean `np.savetxt(f, tag['data-id'])` - since that's what you're printing above?

Comment: And why use numpy to save text to a file ???

Comment: Using numpy just to write to a file is not a good idea imo.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? It'll give you all the value of "data-id" with a text file with those data written within.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = open("testfile.txt","w")

res = requests.get('https://clarity-project.info/tenders/?entiy=38163425&offset=100').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
for item in soup.find_all(class_="table-row"):
    try:
        file.write(item.get('data-id')+'\n')
    except:
        continue
    print(item.get('data-id'))
file.close()
```

Comment: @Sharin I executed code and program work very good. Thank you)))))